# How does YouTube handle such large file uploading?

Tags: memory, file-upload, upload, youtube

When you are running a typical PHP server, you have to set your memory limit higher to allow for larger file uploads. Your memory limit has to be at least as high as the max file size you want to allow.

YouTube allows uploads of I think up to 2GB. Considering how popular YouTube is and how many people upload videos 24/7, how does YouTube handle this? Whatever backend language they are using, I assume they don't have something crazy like `100TB` of memory on each server to allow for 100's or 1,000's of concurrent uploads, etc.

Do they have some sort of unique streaming upload type of thing running, where it doesn't require them to load the entire uploaded file into memory during the upload time? What are they doing that allows so many people to upload such massive files at the same time?